# Earlystopping not working for deep learning model

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, early-stopping

```
adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999, amsgrad = False)
my_model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = adam , metrics = ['accuracy'])

earlystopping = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', verbose = 1, patience = 20, restore_best_weights=True)

history = my_model.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, batch_size = 32, epochs = 20, callbacks=[earlystopping])
```

I applied Earlystopping, then fit function run for all 20 epochs and did not stop even when val_loss increased.
What should be the right way to use earlystopping?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code. You should only decrease the `patience` argument in `EarlyStopping`

You have 20 epochs and setting patience to 20 is the problem.

This is the definition given by Tensorflow:

`patience:  Number of epochs with no improvement after which training will be stopped.`

I propose to change it to this:

`earlystopping = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', verbose = 1, patience = 5, restore_best_weights=True)`

Now if the `val_loss` don't decrease for 5 consecutive epochs, the training will stop.